# How can I move to a specific compass bearing using x and y coordinates while keeping velocity constant?

Tags: vector, trigonometry, sqf

I'm writing a function that determines wind speed and direction over time. Due to API limitations, both **speed and direction are determined with `x` and `y` coordinates.** I.e. `x` for the easterly component in m/s, and `y` for the northerly component in m/s. **`x` and `y` also determine the wind's direction as a compass bearing.**

I'm able to determine wind speed and its compass bearing with the following:

```
// [0.70711, 0.70711] == 1 m/s

_east = 0.70711;
_north = 0.70711;

_vector = sqrt((_east^2) + (_north^2));
_normalisedEast = _east / _vector;
_normalisedNorth = _north / _vector;

_bearing = floor ((_east atan2 _north) + 360 ) % 360;

// The wind is travelling at 1 m/s at 45 degrees
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to express the relationship between the `x` and `y` coordinates and the bearing associated with these, in order to manipulate them independently (or together), and solve for new variables. In other words,  **how do I start with a bearing or speed that I want to move to, and work backwards to new `_east`, `_north` values, given the above?**

How can I use the information gathered here to move to a specific bearing at a specific speed? How can I control both wind speed and direction independently so that either variable can be shifted randomly within a specific range of values?

Examples:

Say the wind is currently pointing at `[2, 2]`, `(0.70711*2)`, which equates to 45°. Changing this to `[1.9, 2.1]` will result in a new bearing of 47° while keeping the wind speed constant (with rounding). Changing this to `[1, 1]` would return the bearing to 45°, but would lower the wind speed, etc. Then, say you wanted the wind to move from 45° to 2° without changing the wind speed... I'd like to be able to do that algorithmically.

(Added  tags as TLDRs.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using both Cartesian coordinates and polar representation of the same vector.

```
x,y =>  
   Magnutude = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
   Angle = atan2(y, x)
```

reverse

```
Magnitude, Angle => 
   x = Magnitude * Cos(Angle)
   y = Magnitude * Sin(Angle)
```

So to rotate vector, change angle with the same magnitude